# Filtering noise from (bass) guitar headphone amp?

Tags: guitar, amplifiers, bass-guitar, noise

For bass guitar practice, I'm using a headphone amp - or rather a preamp with a headphone out - which I then put through a small analogue mixer or directly to headphones. I like the sound of this preamp and I can get a few different tones.

There is one issue however, when I'm using fuzz or overdrive I get a bit of high-pitched whine - which is quite noticeable with headphones (even if I turn down the treble).

Is there a way to get rid of this high pitched noise?

I was thinking some sort of "analogue low pass filter" for headphones - but I couldn't find many of these. I could get an analogue EQ.. but it feels like overkill and they tend to be quite big. If I were using a real amp I could use an EQ pedal... but presumably the don't work that well for headphone rather instrument signal levels.

Perhaps an EQ before would work as well if the noise is coming from the guitar and gettling amplified. Is this likely to work (so that I should buy a pedal to test it out). Also I guess there might just be a noise source...

Comment: Are you plugging the guitar to overdrive and then directly to the headphone preamp? Also, is the noise constant, even if you're not playing, or is it an unwanted high frequency component of the notes you're playing?

Comment: Is there a power supply in the system, or is everything battery powered? I had a similar problem with an overdrive pedal and the source of the noise turned out to be an old switching power supply.

Comment: @user1079505 I'm plugging the guitar directly (using a 2.4 GHz wireless cableless system) into the headphone preamp - the headphone preamp has overdrive and fuzz settings.  Let me double check the second question.

Comment: @ojs That's a good suggestion. i can use the preamp without mains power so I'll pick up a couple of 9V batteries and see how it sounds.

Comment: Another name for an “analogue low pass filter” is just “low pass filter”. There’s tons of them in the world that are analog. Have you tried it without the wireless setup to see if that might be introducing noise?